# Browser Warning "The entire domain cannot be shown"

Tags: browser, security-warning, vivaldi

While visiting a page on Twitter with a short URL, Vivaldi browser warned me "The entire domain cannot be shown. Make sure you trust this website before submitting data."

This video illustrates the display of a tip tool message when I hover the mouse over the browser address bar's warning icon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQkchSr7tvY

Why is the browser warning about the entire domain not being shown when I clearly can see a URL in its entirety?

Comment: I am not going to watch a YouTube video.  Instead do yourself a favor and take 1-2 screenshots, that illustrate the problem. You don't mention what version of Vivaldi you are running or the operating you are running it on.

Comment: @Ramhound I would love to, but I cannot take a screenshot when I hover the icon. You can just just go to second 6 of the video and image will be ready. You need not see the video, just view second 6. Thank you

Comment: I looked at https://twitter.com/johulrich and there's nothing special about it. Are you using a proxy or something that plays with the twitter domain name?

Comment: @u20210512 - Then capture a screenshot of the individual frame.

Comment: Youtube rule #667: always trust a youtuber who blocks comments.

Comment: @harrymc I am not. Simple window home PC, and, that I am aware of, simple installation of Vivaldi browser.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I am sorry, I can be socially inept... is the rule #667 sarcasm?

Comment: @u20210512 Yeah, just a quip regarding the video. By far most content creators allow commenting on videos. The creators who block them are usually flat earthers, alien/ufo truthists, conspiracy theorists and other similar. So to me blocked comments are an immediate indicator that the content might not be entirely trustworthy. Obviously I am not saying every blocker is dodgy, but to me it's not a good first impression. I hope my blurb below clarified some things for you :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thank you for clarifying... Yeah... I have problems of my own :)  The explanation you gave below was new information for me. I have continued to observe Vivaldi and noticed the icon pops up when I navigate/open a new page and quickly disappears. I don't know why it stayed on on that twitter page, and I have not installed a plugin to alert me of such information, but I am satisfied with your explanation. Bests

Comment: @u20210512 Glad to help :-) Could you maybe give a couple of links where you see this happen? It's piquing my interest :-D I'd really like to fix that "I can't be certain..." -part from my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I clearly can see a URL in its entirety

No, you really can't. *You* can see what the browser shows you, and the *browser* shows you what the *site owner* decides. Domain masking is about a decade old thing by now.

Why?

I run a new, hip, trendy company `trndycmpn.com` (you *know* it's hip cuz there's no wovels). I have a webshop that sells hip and trendy stuff. I run a registration page for new customers. And I want *YOU* to be able to talk to *ME DIRECTLY!* so I have a drop-me-a-message -page.

Now as an owner of new, hip, trendy company; do I want you to know I'm running my webshop in `notdodgyshopatall.com`, registrations are done by `honestguyswhodefsdontsellyourdata.com` and my very personal message page by `totallynotbots.com`? Heck no! I obfuscate them, so the addresses you actually see are `shp.trndycmpn.com`, `rgs.trndycmpn.com` and `msg.trndycmpn.com`.

Or maybe I maintain them myself. I just don't want to show you something like `trndycmpn.com/doof/1f4dba13/?_encoding=UTF8&showVariations=true&moreDeals=dd1a2492&smid=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&usragnt=chromium&/os=win10pro&pf_rd_p=dcc84eb6-e4c0-4251-b1c6-6336a677d454&pd_rd_wg=IfVuk&pf_rd_r=ZSJTF5911DW2H6DTYHX9&pd_rd_w=ep7B5&pd_rd_r=bd4e222b-0fd2-4068-bd58-b0d32681d46b&ref_=pd_gw_unk` as that might be a tad more difficult to remember than `shp.trndycmpn.com`. And you might figure out that I'm tracking things like your browser and OS - just to show you relevant offerings, of course. And it doesn't look hip.

You're talking yourself about

> a page on Twitter with a short URL

You didn't provide the page or your Vivaldi version, so I can't verify your experience. I just installed v 4.1 and went to the page shown in the video. I didn't see any other address, and didn't get that warning. Checked a couple of other Twitter pages, but no cigar. Anyway URL shortening / simplifying is one of the reasons for Domain Masking.

So I can't say for certain whether this is Domain Masking or not, but I suspect it is. The way I read it is that the browser (or a plugin?) is notifying that something like Domain Masking is used to hide the true address. It doesn't mean there's something nefarious going on, but the browser couldn't know, so being the nice people they are the browser (or plugin?) devs have decided that it might be an idea to let you know it's happening.